Accessing folder
I want to keep projects in subfolders, e.g., Latex/book/images, where the main folder is Latex, the subfolder is Book, and from the Book folder, I want to be able to access the files in the Images folder. I can access the images folder by specifying /images from the main latex directory but if I put the related files for book in the folder book then I cannot access them when I try to compile.

Please consider adding some MWE to work on.

it's hard to tell as you have provided no information but it sounds like you just need \includegraphics{../images/somefile.png}  using ../ to go up a level.

See also \graphicspath in the user manual of the graphics bundle.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe  you are looking for  import, but see also here.
